# EL expression inside a loop

Tags: jsp, el

I have a loop that creates input fields. Here is the original code (only the relevant pieces):

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
String itemNumber = "itm_num[" + i + "]";
%>

<td><html:text property="<%= itemNumber %>" /></td>

<% } %>
```

I want to set the input values to URL parameters. My URL is something like ordpad.jsp?`Item1=12345&Item2=23456.`

I can set an input field value individually when I am referencing a specific parameter like:

```
 <td><html:text property="<%= itemNumber %>" value="${param['Item1']}" /></td>
```

But of course if I do this in my loop, every field displays `12345`. How do I format the EL expression to return the value of the parameter `Item + i`?

I have tried adding another `String` variable to the first group of code that creates the loop and the variables:

```
 String itemStr = "'Item" + i + "'";
```

and then setting the value on the input field to:

```
  value="${param[<%= itemStr %>]}"
```

but nothing is displayed in any of the input fields.

I have also tried setting the itemStr variable to:

String itemStr = "${param['Item" + i + "']}";

and then setting the value to:

```
 value="<%= itemStr %>"
```

but that only displays the full itemStr as text in the field. The string is not actually evaluated.

Comment: You can improve the formatting of your question by putting code between backtick. (`)

Comment: you could have the item numbers be a comment seperated list of fields and split them